# I Want to access iPhone in built app "Voice Memos"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiorecorder, voice-recording

In my app there is a recording option.

I written code to record the voice by using AVAudioRecorder it will work fine, but my client requirement is it opens the native Voice recorder in ios device that is "Voice Memos". As per my research so many answered that we are unable to access Voice Memos app. I am confused.

Can u please help me there is an any way to access Voice Memos.

Comment: You can't. There is no way for 3rd party apps to launch or use the built-in Voice Memos app.

Comment: can we share the audio file in own ios application from voice memo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Till date it is not allowed to access voice memos recorded by native ios recorder. The best option is to use AVAudioRecorder and let the user record their own memos in your app to upload to the server and access these to show the recorded memos.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.. i'll do with AVAudioRecorder @rachit